# Splitting text using NLTK regex by POS

Tags: python, nltk

I'm experimenting with NLTK to help me parse some text. So far , just using the sent_tokenize function has been very helpful in organizing the text. As an example I have:

```
1 Robins Drive owned by Gregg S. Smith was sold to TeStER, LLC of 494 Bridge Avenue, Suite 101-308, Sheltville AZ 02997 for $27,000.00.
```

using:

```
words =pos_tag(word_tokenize(sentence))
```

I get:

```
[('1', 'CD'), ('Robins', 'NNP'), ('Drive', 'NNP'), ('owned', 'VBN'), ('by', 'IN'), ('Gregg', 'NNP'), ('S.', 'NNP'), ('Smith', 'NNP'), ('was', 'VBD'), ('sold', 'VBN'), ('to', 'TO'), ('TeStER', 'NNP'), (',', ','), ('LLC', 'NNP'), ('of', 'IN'), ('494', 'CD'), ('Bridge', 'NNP'), ('Avenue', 'NNP'), (',', ','), ('Suite', 'NNP'), ('101-308', 'CD'), (',', ','), ('Sheltville', 'NNP'), ('AZ', 'NNP'), ('02997', 'CD'), ('for', 'IN'), ('$', '$'), ('27,000.00', 'CD'), ('.', '.')]
```

I have been looking at various tutorials and the book http://www.nltk.org/book/ , as well as the docs at http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tokenize/regexp.html.

I notice that splitting by the POS 'IN' (Preposition or subordinating conjunction from http://nishutayaltech.blogspot.in/2015/02/penn-treebank-pos-tags-in-natural.html ) would yield some good info. How can I do this?

Comment: What are you after? Parsing the text (ie. obtaining a formal representation of the grammatical structure) or just splitting sentences into hunks of some kind (if so:what kind?)?

Comment: There are 4  semantic strucures (named entities?) in this sentence, if I understand correctly : Address, original owner, new owner, price. I'm trying to figure out how to extract these.

Comment: Ok, I think you want to extract certain roles. If all sentences are structured very similar, you might get there with the [RegexpParser](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.chunk.html#nltk.chunk.regexp.RegexpParser) and write a few rules to extract what you need. Or maybe you can even do named entity recognition only, in combination with some heuristics. Otherwise, you'll need to perform actual parsing.

Comment: Thank you, I will try the regexparser. Can I ask you though, is there an NLTK class that is able to do a regex on both the POS tags and actual string value ? something like "owned by NNP NNP NNP" - if that makes sense?

Comment: I think you can mix literal words and tags in the grammar, but I'm not sure. I couldn't find a comprehensive description of the grammar specs.

Comment: Yeah, I have not been able to find this either. I'll write a follow up question on this. Thank you.

Comment: If you want named entities, do named entity recognition. Don't waste your time with regexps; find or make a training corpus, and train a classifier. Look through the NLTK book for "named entity recognition", and also "chunking".

Comment: Will do, thank you.